bad position of contact points :why?
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class several_adjacents_planes_cut : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject point;
    GameObject monObjet;

    List<GameObject> ListPoints = new List<GameObject>();
    Vector3 echelle_plan;
    
    void Start()
    { //objet auquel ce script est attaché
        monObjet = gameObject;
        echelle_plan = monObjet.GetComponent<Transform>().localScale;       
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        // Vérifiez le tag de l'objet avec lequel cet objet entre en collision
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("plan1"))
        {
            // Accédez au premier point de contact avec Objet1 s'il y en a
            if (col.contacts.Length > 0)
            {
                ContactPoint firstContact = col.contacts[0];
                Vector3 contactPoint = firstContact.point;
                GameObject newPoint = Instantiate(point);
                newPoint.transform.position = contactPoint;
                ListPoints.Add(newPoint);
                Debug.Log("Premier point de contact avec plan1 : " + contactPoint);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Aucun point de contact avec plan1.");
            }
        }
        else if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("plan2"))
        {
            // Accédez au premier point de contact avec Objet2 s'il y en a
            if (col.contacts.Length > 0)
            {
                ContactPoint firstContact = col.contacts[0];
                Vector3 contactPoint = firstContact.point;
                GameObject newPoint = Instantiate(point);
                newPoint.transform.position = contactPoint;
                ListPoints.Add(newPoint);
                Debug.Log("Premier point de contact avec plan2 : " + contactPoint);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Aucun point de contact avec plan2.");
            }
        }
    }
}


The position of the 1st point of contact between the horizontal plane and the 1st vertical plane is tagged "plan1"

The position of the 1st point of contact between the horizontal plane and the 2nd vertical plane is tagged "plan2"


The collider used on each plane is a BoxCollider

The y scale of each plane is 0.1f. The other scales (scale_x and scale_z) are at 1

Sphere has a SphereCollider

All objects have a Rigidbody with constraints checked and UseGravity unchecked


I'm waiting for this:

the expected contact points are framed in black

Please explain what you mean by "bad position of contact points". What values are you getting? What values are you expecting?
